# SQL inner join on alias (for XML)

Tags: sql, xml, join, exists

I have a running query where I need to expand the XML hierarchy.

The existing query does this (WORKING):

```
select a.fields, (select c.fields from c), 
(select d.fields from d), (select e.fields from e)
from a 
--REPAIR ORDERS, PARTS, LABOR, NARRATIVE
```

I need to create another level at b (THIS IS THE JOB ORDER FOR REPAIR ORDERS, and aliased as bb):

```
--REPAIR ORDERS, JOB ID (JOB ID/PARTS, JOB ID/LABOR, JOB ID/NARRATIVE)

select a.fields, select b.fields, (select c.fields from c), 
(select d.fields from d), (select e.fields from e) from b)
bb
from a
```

so here's the code (this inner join is killing me):
(also, think as REPAIR NARRATIVES as C and once I get this going I need to add D & E)

IT's the INNER JOIN at the comments line which is stopping me:

```
declare @OEMDEALERCODE nvarchar(20),@SDate smalldatetime,@EDate smalldatetime,@DMxServiceROJobStatus_ReadyToInvoice int
SET @SDate = '01/01/2013'
SET @EDate = '12/31/2013'
SET @DMxServiceROJobStatus_ReadyToInvoice = dbo.[fn_DMxSysGetEnumItemValue](N'DMxServiceROJobStatus', N'ReadyToInvoice')


-- JobId hierarchy
select  ff.QualifyingROX, ff.JobId, ff.JobName, 
(
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT DISTINCT --REPAIR NARRATIVE
        Concern, Cause, Correction, CauseMore, ConcernMore, CorrectionMore
    FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.DMXDEALERINFORMATIONTABLE.OEMDEALERCODE, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.ROID, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.JOBID, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.STATUS, 
            DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1.TEXT CONCERN, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT.TEXT CAUSE, 
            DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.TEXT CORRECTION, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CUSTOMCAUSETEXT CAUSEMORE, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CUSTOMCONCERNTEXT CONCERNMORE, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CUSTOMCORRECTIONTEXT CORRECTIONMORE, 
            DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.RECVERSION Expr5, 
            MAX(dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.RECVERSION) Expr4, 
            MAX(dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT.RECVERSION) Expr3, 
            MAX(DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1.RECVERSION) Expr1, 
            MAX(DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.RECVERSION) Expr2
        FROM dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
            dbo.DMXDEALERINFORMATIONTABLE (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE (NOLOCK) ON dbo.DMXDEALERINFORMATIONTABLE.PARTITION = dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.PARTITION ON 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.ROTABLEREF = dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.RECID LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2 ON 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CORRECTIONREF = DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.RECID LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT ON dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CAUSEREF = dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT.RECID LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1 ON 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CONCERNREF = DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1.RECID
        GROUP BY dbo.DMXDEALERINFORMATIONTABLE.OEMDEALERCODE, dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.ROID, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.JOBID, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.STATUS, DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1.TEXT, dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT.TEXT, 
            DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.TEXT, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CUSTOMCAUSETEXT, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CUSTOMCONCERNTEXT, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.CUSTOMCORRECTIONTEXT, DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.RECID, DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.PARTITION, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT.RECVERSION, dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT.PARTITION, DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1.PARTITION, 
            dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.RECVERSION, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.RECID, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.PARTITION, 
            DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1.RECVERSION, DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_1.RECID, dbo.DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT.RECID, 
            DMXSERVICECCCSTATEMENT_2.RECVERSION
        having dbo.DMXDEALERINFORMATIONTABLE.OEMDEALERCODE = @OEMDEALERCODE 
        --and dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.ROID = ff.QualifyingROX 
        and dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.STATUS=@DMxServiceROJobStatus_ReadyToInvoice
        ORDER BY Expr4 DESC, Expr3 DESC, Expr1 DESC, Expr2 DESC
        ) cc 
        inner join ff on cc.ROID = ff.QualifyingROX
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT --REPAIR NARRATIVE
        ee.JobId, ee.JobName, ee.QualifyingROX
     from 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT 
        dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.ROID QualifyingROX, 
        dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.JOBID JobId, 
        MAX(DISTINCT dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.NAME) JobName
        FROM dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE (nolock) INNER JOIN dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB (NOLOCK) ON dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.RECID = dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.ROTABLEREF
        GROUP BY dbo.DMXSERVICEROTABLE.ROID, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.JOBID
        ORDER BY QualifyingROX, dbo.DMXSERVICEROJOB.JOBID
    ) ee 
) ff
for XML PATH ('JobDetail'), ROOT ('Jobs'), TYPE
```

Comment: Is this sql server and if so what version?

Comment: (so sorry) I just noticed this was still open. I figured this ALL OF THIS out back in April (and simply didn't notice it until today).